# the skip=1 has no effect on textConnect when read.table

Tags: r

I want to skip the first line when reading the text.

```
raw_data='
编号,性别,序号,民族,籍贯,系部
1,男,20130990,壮族,广西省,旅游系
24,男,20130520,汉族,广东省,经管系
48,女,20131065,汉族,河北省,艺术系,,
49,女,20131066,汉族,湖南省,艺术系,,
50,女,20131067,汉族,广东省,艺术系,,
129,男,20130340,汉族,海南省,经管系
131,男,20130342,汉族,四川省,经管系'
x <- textConnection(raw_data)
data<-read.table(x,sep=",",skip=1,col.names=1:8,fill=TRUE)
```

What i want is :

```
   X1 X2       X3   X4     X5     X6 X7 X8
1   1 男 20130990 壮族 广西省 旅游系 NA NA
2  24 男 20130520 汉族 广东省 经管系 NA NA
3  48 女 20131065 汉族 河北省 艺术系 NA NA
4  49 女 20131066 汉族 湖南省 艺术系 NA NA
5  50 女 20131067 汉族 广东省 艺术系 NA NA
6 129 男 20130340 汉族 海南省 经管系 NA NA
7 131 男 20130342 汉族 四川省 经管系 NA NA
```

not:

```
    X1   X2       X3   X4     X5     X6 X7 X8
1 编号 性别     序号 民族   籍贯   系部 NA NA
2    1   男 20130990 壮族 广西省 旅游系 NA NA
3   24   男 20130520 汉族 广东省 经管系 NA NA
4   48   女 20131065 汉族 河北省 艺术系 NA NA
5   49   女 20131066 汉族 湖南省 艺术系 NA NA
6   50   女 20131067 汉族 广东省 艺术系 NA NA
7  129   男 20130340 汉族 海南省 经管系 NA NA
8  131   男 20130342 汉族 四川省 经管系 NA NA
```

Maybe i can not skip the first line in the form of read.table(textConnection()) ?

Comment: This title is not very descriptive of the actual problem, but I'm not sure what the proper title should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra newline in your specification.  You can skip two lines, with the data as it is, to remove the extra newline and the first line:

```
 data<-read.table(x,sep=",",skip=2,col.names=1:8,fill=TRUE)
```

Or you can remove the extra newline and skip the first line alone:

```
raw_data='编号,性别,序号,民族,籍贯,系部
1,男,20130990,壮族,广西省,旅游系
24,男,20130520,汉族,广东省,经管系
48,女,20131065,汉族,河北省,艺术系,,
49,女,20131066,汉族,湖南省,艺术系,,
50,女,20131067,汉族,广东省,艺术系,,
129,男,20130340,汉族,海南省,经管系
131,男,20130342,汉族,四川省,经管系'
x <- textConnection(raw_data)
data<-read.table(x,sep=",",skip=1,col.names=1:8,fill=TRUE)

data
   X1 X2       X3   X4     X5     X6 X7 X8
1   1 男 20130990 壮族 广西省 旅游系 NA NA
2  24 男 20130520 汉族 广东省 经管系 NA NA
3  48 女 20131065 汉族 河北省 艺术系 NA NA
4  49 女 20131066 汉族 湖南省 艺术系 NA NA
5  50 女 20131067 汉族 广东省 艺术系 NA NA
6 129 男 20130340 汉族 海南省 经管系 NA NA
7 131 男 20130342 汉族 四川省 经管系 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the first line is actually an empty character vector.
We can see it with `readLines`

```
> x <- textConnection(raw_data)
> readLines(x)
## [1] ""                                    "编号,性别,序号,民族,籍贯,系部"      
## [3] "1,男,20130990,壮族,广西省,旅游系"    "24,男,20130520,汉族,广东省,经管系"  
## [5] "48,女,20131065,汉族,河北省,艺术系,," "49,女,20131066,汉族,湖南省,艺术系,,"
## [7] "50,女,20131067,汉族,广东省,艺术系,," "129,男,20130340,汉族,海南省,经管系" 
## [9] "131,男,20130342,汉族,四川省,经管系"
```

We can use `sub` to remove that extra new line at the beginning of `raw_data`

```
> read.table(text = sub("\\n", "", raw_data), 
             sep = ",", skip = 1, fill = TRUE)
##    V1 V2       V3   V4     V5     V6 V7 V8
## 1   1 男 20130990 壮族 广西省 旅游系 NA NA
## 2  24 男 20130520 汉族 广东省 经管系 NA NA
## 3  48 女 20131065 汉族 河北省 艺术系 NA NA
## 4  49 女 20131066 汉族 湖南省 艺术系 NA NA
## 5  50 女 20131067 汉族 广东省 艺术系 NA NA
## 6 129 男 20130340 汉族 海南省 经管系 NA NA
## 7 131 男 20130342 汉族 四川省 经管系 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use data<-data[-1,]
```

if first line is the header, use header=FALSE.